# Translating Mouse gestures into Numbers (.NET)

Tags: .net, mouse, numbers, gestures

I am looking for a way to translate mouse movements - while the left mouse button is kept pressed down - into numbers 0 - 9.

Are there any existing .NET libraries for this?

many Thanks for any advice on this,
Kave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used, but maybe [this library](http://www.codeplex.com/mousegestures/) can help you.

Comment: Hi. I have tested it today. Its interesting. but Source code is not included and I cant see how it could be extended to use numbers as gestures instead...but thanks

Comment: Usually on CodePlex, the source is there. On the project site, there is a toolbar with links like 'Home', 'Downloads', etc. The 5th one is 'Source code', go there and you'll have a download link for the source code on the far right (below 'latest version')